# Not sure on how to randomize this

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, random

im trying to randomze a set a results from the database,

this is the bases of the array:

```
    array (size=30)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string 'jordan' (length=6)
  2 => string 'chris' (length=5)
  3 => string '1' (length=1)
  4 => string '1' (length=1)
  5 => string 'card1, card2, card3, card4, card5, card6, card7, card8' (length=54)
  6 => string 'card16, card20, card30, card40, card50, card60, card70, card80' (length=62)
  7 => string '' (length=0)
  8 => string '' (length=0)
  9 => string '' (length=0)
  10 => string '' (length=0)
  11 => string '' (length=0)
  12 => string '' (length=0)
  13 => string '' (length=0)
  14 => string '' (length=0)
  15 => string '' (length=0)
  16 => string '' (length=0)
  17 => string '' (length=0)
  18 => string '' (length=0)
  19 => string '' (length=0)
  20 => string '' (length=0)
  21 => string '' (length=0)
  22 => string '' (length=0)
  23 => string '' (length=0)
  24 => string '' (length=0)
  25 => string '' (length=0)
  26 => string '' (length=0)
  27 => string '2013-11-21 04:23:19' (length=19)
  28 => string '0' (length=1)
  29 => string '0' (length=1)
```

im wanting to pull the data from array[5] and shuffle it/randomize it

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($cards, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    var_dump($row);
     var_dump(array_rand($row[6], 2 ));

}
```

i've tried various things and now im just at the stage of getting confused even more than i did when i first started can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Explode your string first:

```
$cards = explode(",", $row[6]);
```

then, randomize, using [`shuffle`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php), and implode:

```
shuffle($cards);
$result = implode(",", $cards);
```

it should now be a shuffled list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the php function [shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) in order to randomize in array.
Then you just have to pull the data you want to an array, shuffle it and then display it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   function getR($ipt)
    {

    $pieces = explode(",", $ipt);
    return  $pieces[mt_rand(0,count($pieces)-1)];
    }


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($cards, MYSQL_NUM))
 {
     echo getR($row[5]);
}
```